# Is there a stride setting for PIC32MX DMA?

Tags: pic, dma

I'm reading the registers in the user guide for the DMA and I don't see one, but I wanted to make sure.   I was hoping that in addition to cell size there was a stride size as well.  So for instance if I had 1000 bytes but I only want the DMA to transfer every other byte.  With another DMA I could set my transfer cell size as 1, my stride as say 2, and my length as 1000.   Then I'd end up with 500bytes, or every other byte from the source, at my destination.

Comment: Why would you do that? Interleaving data in memory seems an added complexity I would want to avoid.

Comment: I have real time audio streaming in over I2S, which means I get two samples, left and right per cycle.   There's no way to disable this, there's a mono mode that just duplicates the right to the left channel.  So I end up DMAing this into a page buffer in memory.   Now I'm writing this to external flash which has a several ms page write time so I need to DMA it out and I only have a limited amount of time.  I'm on the edge with this timing, so if I could DMA only 1/2 of the data I'd have more margin or be able to up the sample rate, or use half the storage space.

Comment: There's not enough cycles for the CPU to get involved on every page write to say copy the data.

Answer (score 1):

The DMA in the PIC32MX can not skip any bytes. You can set the cell size and block size. To possibly achieve the effect your looking for you could use channel chaining, sometimes called ping pong mode. To achieve an uninterrupted stream two DMA channels are used. While one is transmitting the second is prepped and when the first finishes the second kicks in automatically.

With this setup you could use a for() loop for instance to sort sort the data set to eliminate every one. Set the DMA to transmit. Then sort the data set for the second DMA channel and wait for the first to finish. When it's done the second channel kicks in seamlessly and you can sort the data set for the first channel.